# Problems with routing using.htaccess and localhost url

Tags: php, .htaccess, localhost, wamp

I am trying to route traffic from my delopment url to my MCV controller using mod_rewrite for Apache. But i keep getting a **"Internal Server Error"**.

**Spects:** Windows 10, WAMP

**Localhost url**: taskmanager.local

**.htaccess file:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Multiviews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase taskcomplete.local/public
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Virtual Host:

```
# TaskComplete
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "D:\Dropbox\web\projects\php\task_complete"
  ServerName taskcomplete.local
  <Directory "D:\Dropbox\web\projects\php\task_complete">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: "Internal server error" == look into the error.log. Nobody can remotely guess the actual problem. Also: enable the RewriteLog.

Comment: @mario, "RewriteBase: argument is not a valid URL, referer: http://taskcomplete.local/" Not sure what part is 'invalid'

Comment: Changed `RewriteBase` from `/taskcomplete.local/public` to just `/public`and noe the url `http://taskcomplete.local/public` works but i was hoping to make the localhost url use `public` as it's root folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after some random fumbling i solved the issue. I made some changes to my `.htaccess` file and `httpd-vhost.conf` file and everything and now the `localhost` url points to the `/public` folder as it should.

**.htaccess file:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Multiviews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /public                          
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

### **CHANGES** `taskcomplete.local/public` **=>** `/public`

**Virtual Host:**

```
# TaskComplete
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "D:\Dropbox\web\projects\php\task_complete"
  ServerName taskcomplete.local
  <Directory "D:\Dropbox\web\projects\php\task_complete">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

### **CHANGES** `D:\Dropbox\web\projects\php\task_complete` => `D:\Dropbox\web\projects\php\task_complete\public`